# Running Wordpress on Localhost - URLs output doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a local server using xampp on my computer to develop a wp plugin.
For that plugin, I need to get some path to a file in my /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin folder.
However, when I use functions such as content_url() (click [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url) for reference), the URL that is put out is always containing localhost/localhost/rest/of/my/path instead of only localhost/rest/of/my/path

```
 $dir = content_url() . '/plugins/myplugin/myplugin-admin.php';
 add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'Pages Admin', 'switch_themes', $dir, '', '', 6 );
```

Do you guys have any idea, why it is that way and what I can do to change it?
Thanks in advance,
r-jay

Comment: Witch URL do you have in *admin panel > Settings > General* in "Wordpress adress" and "Site address" ?

Comment: You should check out these fun constants for your own happyness: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Answer (score 0):

I think its come from admin 1) general settings.Please check your site url and home url
2) if you have database then you can check also wp_options table. 3)one more think if this two solution not worked check your .htacces file.

May its help

Thanks